# CakePHP bizarre error

Tags: php, cakephp, overriding

I include a PHP simple file by: `require 'basic.php';` in `bootstrap.php`.

Here is the codes:

```
<?php
override_function('strlen', '$string', 'return override_strlen($string);');
function override_strlen($string){
        return strlen($string);  
}
```

There is this error:

```
Fatal error: Class 'Helper' not found in ...\app\View\Helper\ShellHelper.php on line 7
```

I become confused.

If I remove `override_function('strlen', '$string', 'return override_strlen($string);');` the problem disappear.

[image]

Comment: Are you sure that it's even possible to call the original in an overriden function? Without having tried that, I could imagine that this creates an infinite loop, or other unexpected behavior. That being said, whenever receiving errors, please always post **the _complete_ error**, that is, **including the _full_ stacktrace** (ideally copied from the logs where it is available in a properly readable fashion), even if the problem might be obvious to people who are familiar with CakePHP - thanks!

Comment: That was an example from PHP.net that I put there. My code has allergy with `override_function` function. I write also just this code: `override_function('strlen', '$string', 'return 3;');` but it doesn't work

Comment: Looking at the stacktrace, the initial (fatal) error occurs at bootstrap time in your `basic.php` file, and the missing helper error is probably just a side effect and obscures the first error. I'd suggest to test that `override_function` stuff outside of CakePHP first to ensure that it actually works.